# Publishing Static Code Metric reports in Jenkins using declarative pipeline(Jenkinsfile)

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

I am building a simple CI pipeline for my python code in Jenkins using Jenkinsfile, which basically does the following things:

> 1. Creating test environment and installing dependencies.
> 2. Running static code metrics:
>
>    - various raw metrics : SLOC, comment lines, blank lines, Cyclomatic Complexity, the Maintainability Index etc.
>    - tests coverage reports using coverage
>    - errors and style check using pylint
> 3. Testing pulled source code (Unit testing)

So lets say i have this stage for example, for "Static code metrics":

```
...
        stage('Static code metrics') {
            steps {
                echo "Raw metrics"
                sh  ''' radon raw --json my_python_repo/ > raw_report.json
                        radon cc --json my_python_repo/ > cc_report.json
                        radon mi --json my_python_repo/ > mi_report.json
                        //TODO: add conversion and HTML publisher step
                    '''
            }
        }

...
```

As you see above, the reports are saved in .json format. **I need to figure out a way to publish these reports in a pretty visual way on Jenkins dashboard.**
One of the steps is to convert the .json files to HTML and then use HTML publisher plugin to publish reports but i don't know what tool to use.
If there is way to solve this or any other way to publish these reports on jenkins dashboard, please provide the solution.

> Lets say content of **mi_report.json** is:

```
 {"my_python_repo/code.py": {"mi": 16.42950884051172, "rank": "B"}, "my_python_repo/test.py": {"mi": 33.532817596089814, "rank": "A"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no Jenkins-ready tool to publish custom JSON as HTML.
But you can use [warnings](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin) plugin to publish your metrics in the Jenkins way.
[Here small instruction on how to configure Jenkins to parse radon reports](https://www.paulbutcher.space/blog/2018/12/07/jenkins-warnings-radon).

Comment: the last link is broken.